# How to extend a class in a wordpress plugin from theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, plugins

I am trying to extend a class that is inside a plugin from my theme, but if I check the class to be extended with `if(class_exists('Hello_Class'))` I can see the class is not available. The plugin structure is something like this:

```
    class PluginCore {
        public static $info;

        function __construct() {
            add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array( $this, 'after_setup_theme' ), 12 );
        }

        function after_setup_theme() {
            // the class I want extend
            require_once '/Hello_Class.php';
        }

}
new PluginCore();
```

I want to extend the class "Hello_Class", I tried to get this work using hook like `after_setup_theme` and `init`, but nothing works. Is there a way to
make this work.

Comment: Plugins may or may not be activated. Of course you can check (at some reasonable point) whether the plugin is activated and extend the class in your theme code. But I think much better approach is to make a new plugin which requires the other plugin and extends the old plugin';s class outside of your theme. Then you can control when and how your plugins gets activated and so on..

Comment: Plugin is active. I have tried to extend from a custom plugin, still no luck. Is there anything that is related with "after_setup_theme" hook that is loading the actual class!

Comment: Then you either check if class exists at a point of execution where the class is not yet loaded, or the plugin loads that class conditionaly only in some cases.